# Workbench Settings: "Preferred Query Batch Size" parameter missing?

Tags: batch, workbench, size, dataloader-batch

### Theory

1. 

On [Workbench's Wiki](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/wiki#query--search) in the *"How do I call queryMore()?"* question, is written:

> (...) The query batch size can be changed with the *"Preferred Query Batch Size"* setting on the Settings menu.

2. 

Also, on the [update.php page](https://workbench.developerforce.com/update.php), the tooltip next to *"Process records asynchronously via Bulk API"* checkbox says:

> (...) Batch size and concurrency options are available in Settings.

3. 

Finally, on [this GitHub extract](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/main/workbench/config/defaults.php#L604), lines 604-612 mention the *queryOptions_batchSize* parameter:

```
    $config["queryOptions_batchSize"] = array(
        "label" => "Preferred Query Batch Size",
        "description" => "Requested query batch size. This is not a guaranteed value and depends on the data set being returned.",
        "default" => 500,
        "overrideable" => true,
        "dataType" => "int",
        "minValue" => 200,
        "maxValue" => 2000
    );
```

### Practice

**However**,

- when I go to the [settings.php page](https://workbench.developerforce.com/settings.php), I cannot find anywhere the *"Preferred Query Batch Size"* setting, nor any setting containing the word "batch" or "size"
- *(update)* and as Vinay is mentioning in the comments below, people are [requesting this feature on IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmdWUAR/developer-workbench-allow-to-set-the-batch-size).

**→ Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set batch size in workbench.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmdWUAR/developer-workbench-allow-to-set-the-batch-size).